# I am trying to create a forcedirectedgraph using d3.js to visualize the architecture dynamically

Tags: json, d3.js, hyperlink, visualization, d3-force-directed

The sample JSON file containing the data looks like this :

```
services {  
    service name1: []
    exposed interfaces: []
    consumed interfaces: []
},
{ 
    service name2: []
    exposed interfaces: []
    consumed interfaces: []
},
{ 
    service name3: []
    exposed interfaces: []
    consumed interfaces: []
}
interfaces {
    interface name1:
        protocol stack:[]
},
interfaces {
    interface name1:
        protocol stack:[]
},
interfaces {
    interface name1:
        protocol stack:[]
}
```

I am trying to connect the services with their consumed interfaces, and exposed interfaces and the problem I am facing is with links, I am either able to connect only a few of the links of the services and other services and nodes are left without any connections even if they are related with interfaces and due this i guess force simulation is also not working and all the nodes are just lying in the center,  the code here is as follows:

````
    ```

    // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
    var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 30},
    width = 1200 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 700 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
 
    servicesColor = "green"
    interfacesColor = "brown"
    inputColor = "blue"
    outputColor = "pink"

    var sourceData = {}

    suggestionsElement = document.getElementById("suggestions")

    function dataPreProcessing(data){
        console.log("processing the services");
        data.services = data.services.map(d => {
            d.type = "services"
            d.id=d.name
            d.clickToggle = false;
            return d;
    
        });


        console.log("processing the interfaces");
        data.interfaces = data.interfaces.map(d => {
            d.type = "interfaces"
            d.id=d.name
            d.clickToggle = false;
            return d;
        });

        data.nodes = data.services;
        data.nodes = data.nodes.concat(data.interfaces);

        data.links=[]



        data.nodes.forEach(d=>{
            if(d.type ==="services"){
                d.exposedInterfaces.forEach(b=>{
                    data.links.push(
                        {
                            "source": b,
                            "target": d.id
                        }
                    )
                })
                d.consumedInterfaces.forEach(b=>{
                    data.links.push(
                        {
                            "source": d.id,
                            "target": b
                        }
                    )
                })
            }
        })

        return data;
    }

    function visualize(data) {
        //dataPreProcessing(data);
        // Initialize the links
        // append the svg object to the body of the page
        var svg = d3.select("#vizBox")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom).call(d3.zoom().on("zoom",                                 
    function () {
            svg.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
        }))
        .append("g");

        // Let's list the force we wanna apply on the network
    var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
        .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }))
        .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-500))
        .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

    function dragstarted(d) {
        if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
        simulation.force("link", null).force("charge", null).force("center", null);
        d.fx = d.x;
        d.fy = d.y;
    }

    function dragged(d) {
        d.fx = d3.event.x;
        d.fy = d3.event.y;
    }

    function dragended(d) {
        if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
        d3.event.x = null;
        d3.event.fy = null;
    }

    // tooltip
    tooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").style("width","fit-                
    content").style("height","auto").style("background","#f8f8f8")
   .style("opacity","1").style("position","absolute").style("visibility","hidden").style("box-                
   shadow","0px 0px 6px #7861A5").style("padding","10px");

        var link = svg
            .selectAll("line")
            .data(data.links)
            .enter()
            .append("line")
            .style("stroke", "black")

        // Initialize the nodes
        var node = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "nodes")
            .selectAll("g")
            .data(data.nodes)
            .enter().append("g");

        var circles = node.append("circle")
            .attr("r", 10)
            .attr("fill",function(d){return d.type==="services"? servicesColor:         
    interfacesColor});

        // Create a drag handler and append it to the node object instead
        var drag_handler = d3.drag()
            .on("start", dragstarted)
            .on("drag", dragged)
            .on("end", dragended);

        drag_handler(node);

        var lables = node.append("text")
        .text(function(d) {
            return d.id;
        })
        .attr('x', 12)
        .attr('y', 3);

        node.on("click", (d) => {
            if(!d.clickToggle){
                tooltip.style("visibility","visible")
                .style("top",(d3.event.pageY-30)+"px").style("left",(d3.event.pageX+20)+"px");
                let aTags = d.type === "services" ? "<a Source Documentation</a>  <br/>": "";
                let htmlValue = "<strong>Name: </strong>"+d.name+"<br/><strong>Type:         
    </strong>"+d.type+" <br/>"+aTags+"<strong>JSON:</strong> <br/><div style=\"width: 300px; 
    height: 300px; overflow: scroll;\"><pre><code >"+hljs.highlightAuto(JSON.stringify(d,null, 
    2)).value+"</code></pre></div>";
                tooltip.html(htmlValue);
                d.clickToggle = true;
            }
            else{
                tooltip.style("visibility","hidden");
                d.clickToggle = false;
            }

            if(d.type == "services"){
                svg.selectAll("circle").style("fill", (iterNode)=>{
                    if(d.exposedInterfaces.length == 0){
                        iterNode.inUse = false;
                        return iterNode.type=== "services"? servicesColor: interfacesColor;
                
                    }
                    if(d.exposedInterfaces.some((x) => x == iterNode.id)){
                        iterNode.inUse = true;
                        return outputColor;
                    }else{
                        iterNode.inUse = false;
                        return iterNode.type=== "services"? servicesColor: interfacesColor;
                
                    }
                });

               svg.selectAll("circle").style("fill", (iterNode)=>{
                    if( iterNode.inUse){
                        return outputColor;
                    }
                    if(d.consumedInterfaces.length == 0){
                        return iterNode.type=== "services"? servicesColor: interfacesColor;
                    }
                    if(d.consumedInterfaces.some((x) => x == iterNode.id)){
                        return inputColor;
                    }else{
                        return iterNode.type=== "services"? servicesColor: interfacesColor;
                    }
                });
            }
        })

        simulation
        .nodes(data.nodes)
        .on("tick", ticked);

        simulation.force("link")
        .links(data.links);

        function ticked() {
            link
                .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
                .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
                .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
                .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

            node
        .attr("transform", function(d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
        })
        }
    
    }

    d3.json("/data/api.json",(data) => {
        sourceData = data;
        data = window.dataPreProcessing(data);
        visualize(data);
    });

    function suggest(value){
        filteredData = [];
        if(!!value){
            filteredData = sourceData.nodes.filter((d)=> {
                return d.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) >= 0;
            })
        }


        filteredData = filteredData.slice(0, 3);

        console.log(filteredData, value, filteredData.length);

        if(filteredData.length === 0){
            d3.select("#suggestions").html("");
            d3.select("#suggestions").style("opacity", "0")
            setVisibility("none");
            return;
        }

        else{
            d3.select("#suggestions").html("");

            d3.select("#suggestions").selectAll("div")
            .data(filteredData)
            .enter()
            .append("div")
            .attr("id","suggestionItem")
            .text((d)=> d.name).on("click",(d) => { 
                d3.select("#suggestions").html("");
                SearchData = {};
                SearchData.nodes = [d];
                SearchData.links = [d.exposedInterfaces, d.consumedInterfaces];

                d3.select("#vizBox").html("");
                document.getElementById("searchInput").value = d.name;
                visualize(SearchData);

            });
        }

    }

    function change(){
        var value = document.getElementById("searchInput").value;
        suggest(value);
        setVisibility("block");
        d3.select("#suggestions").style("opacity", "1")
    }

    function inputFocusOut(){
        setVisibility("none");
        d3.select("#suggestions").style("opacity", "0")
    }

    function setVisibility(value){
        suggestionsElement.style.display= value;
    }

    function reset(){
        d3.select("#vizBox").html("");
        document.getElementById("searchInput").value = "";

        setTimeout(d3.json("/data/api.json",(data) => {
            data = dataPreProcessing(data);
            visualize(sourceData);
        }), 5000);

    }
    ```
````

Comment: Can you provide a subset of the json data you use for real ? In particular it could be interesting to see what the exposedInterfaces array looks like.

Comment: thankyou so much for the reply, I have resolved the issue, data was the problem, interface names were not provided for most of them, and the loop used to end when it didn't find the interface it is searching for. I have another query it is: with the search box, when I am trying to search for the element and its connections, only the element is shown but not its connections, could you help me with that? thankyou in advance.